# por que sale este error? Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class

Tags: php, session

Tengo dos archivos uno llamado Cart.php donde tengo la clase Cart y la sentencia session_start(), y otro archivo que se llama query.php donde tengo todo el SQL, el punto es que necesito usar una variable $_SESSION[] y para ello coloque el "include: Cart.php" de primero ya que ese archivo contiene el session_start() y tambien por que necesito incluir el archivo si o si por la clase Cart.

```html
include ('includes/Cart.php');
include ('includes/query.php');
$cart = new Cart;
```

pero al parecer me da este error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class en la linea 2, no lo entiendo por que estoy aplicando el $cart = new Cart; en la linea 3 y en la linea 2 solo utilizo un include que no usa la clase Cart.

el error ya no me aparece cuando lo invierto:

```html
include ('includes/query.php');
include ('includes/Cart.php');
$cart = new Cart;
```

pero si hago eso ya no puedo usar la variable $_SESSION[] por que el session_start() esta en el archivo Cart.php

por favor si alguien sabe que esta pasando me ayudaria bastante

Comment: query.php usa la clas cart?

Comment: no la utilizo, en query.php solo tengo un include 'data.php'; que unicamente tiene la conexion de la BD, por eso me resulta muy rato que me aparezca ese error

Comment: Porfavor, pon el mensaje de error **completo**

Answer (score 0):

A simple vista, y sin el mensaje de error completo, puedo asumir que tienes dos errores:

1) Cuando vas a importar clases a otro documento, ocupa `include_once()` o `require_once()` par importar la clase, ya que si no lo haces, está clase se importará varias veces creándote un error de duplicación de clases.

2) A la hora de que instancias tu clase **Cart** has olvidado los paréntesis. La instanciación correcta sería `$cart = new Cart();`

Antes de todo esto, verifíca que el nombre de la instancia de tu clase es la misma que la que tienes cuando la declaraste, incluyendo mayúsculas y minúsculas.